# Independence over A implies independence over the algebraic closure of $A$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a first order theory $\mathcal{C}$ be its monster model. Assume that $T$ is stable, let $A \subseteq \mathcal{C}$. Is it true that if $\bar{c}$ and $\bar{d}$ are tuples such that $\bar{c} \smile_{A} \bar{d}$ (i.e.$ \bar{c}$ is independent from $\bar{d}$ over $A$)
 then $\bar{c}$ is independent from $\bar{d}$ over $acl(A)$ (i.e. over the algebraic closure of $A$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and even in simple theories (every stable theory is simple). This is already stated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2158929/661457), but there is no proof there. So let's do that.

I am not sure what definition of independence you use, but we can work with just its properties (which hold in any simple theory):

- **Algebraic closure:** for any $c$ and $A$ we have $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A \operatorname{acl}(A)$.
- **Monotonicity and transitivity:** $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A BE$ if and only if $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A B$ and $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_{AB} E$. From left to right is called *monotonicity* and the other direction is *transitivity*.

> **Claim.** From the above properties we can deduce
>   $$ c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A D \Longleftrightarrow c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A AD. $$

**Proof.** We always have $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A A$ (which follows from *algebraic closure* and then *monotonicity*). Then apply *transitivity* with $A$ in the roles of $A$ and $B$, and $D$ in the role of $E$. This gives the left to right direction, the other direction is just *monotonicity*.

Now, let's assume $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A d$, then using the claim we have $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A Ad$. By *algebraic closure*, we have $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_{Ad} \operatorname{acl}(Ad)$. So by *transitivity* we find $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_A \operatorname{acl}(Ad)$. Then applying *monotonicity* once gives $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_{\operatorname{acl}(A)} \operatorname{acl}(Ad)$, and again finally yields $c \overset{\vert}{\smile}_{\operatorname{acl}(A)} d$.

Using similar techniques you can put the $\operatorname{acl}$ in different places (and in multiple places). In other words, independence in simple theories does not care about algebraic closure. Although you will also need the *symmetry* property for this (being able to 'swap' the left and right side of $\overset{\vert}{\smile}$), but that still holds in all simple theories (and is in fact equivalent to the theory being simple).

A proof of the properties I mentioned in terms of dividing can be found in, for example, *A course in Model Theory* by Katrin Tent and Martin Ziegler. The property I named *algebraic closure* is Remark 7.1.3 there and *monotonicity and transitivity* is corollary 7.2.17.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another argument, working directly from the definitions of forking and dividing. So it holds in any theory (I won't assume stability or simplicity). Let $B = \text{acl}(A)$.

> (1) A formula $\varphi(x,d)$ divides over $A$ if and only if it divides over $B$.

If $I = (d_i)_{i\in \omega}$ is a $B$-indiscernible sequence with $d_0 = d$ witnessing dividing over $B$, then $I$ is also $A$-indiscernible, so it witnesses dividing over $A$. Note we didn't use $B = \text{acl}(A)$ here, just $A\subseteq B$.

Conversely, if $I = (d_i)_{i\in \omega}$ is an $A$-indiscernible sequence with $d_0 = d$ witnessing dividing over $A$, then since [an $A$-indiscernible sequence is automatically $\text{acl}(A)$-indiscernible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695557/if-cali-is-a-indiscernible-sequence-over-a-then-it-is-indiscernible-over), $I$ also witnesses dividing over $B$.

> (2) A formula $\varphi(x,d)$ forks over $A$ if and only if it forks over $B$.

This follows immediately from (1).

> (3) $\text{tp}(c/Ad)$ forks over $A$ if and only if $\text{tp}(c/Bd)$ forks over $B$.

Suppose $\text{tp}(c/Ad)$ forks over $A$. Then it contains a formula $\varphi(x,a,d)$ which forks over $A$. By (2), $\varphi(x,a,d)$ also forks over $B$, and $\varphi(x,a,d)\in \text{tp}(c/Bd)$, so this type forks over $B$.

Conversely, suppose $\text{tp}(c/Bd)$ forks over $B$. Then there is a formula $\psi(x,a,b,d)\in \text{tp}(c/Bd)$ (notation: $a\in A$, $b\in B\setminus A$) which forks over $B$, and hence forks over $A$ by (2). The problem is that $\psi(x,a,b,d)\notin \text{tp}(c/Ad)$, since it contains parameters $b\in B\setminus A$.

To fix this, let $b_1,\dots,b_n$ be the finitely many realizations of $\text{tp}(b/Ad)$ (finitely many because $b\in B = \text{acl}(A)$). These are the points in the orbit of $b$ under the action of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{M}/Ad)$. Since forking is automorphism invariant, $\psi(x,a,b_i,d)$ forks over $A$ for all $i$. And since forking formulas are closed under disjunction, $$\varphi(x,a,b_1,\dots,b_n,d) = \bigvee_{i=1}^n \psi(x,a,b_i,d)$$ forks over $A$. But the set defined by $\varphi(x,a,b_1,\dots,b_n,d)$ is fixed by the action of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{M}/Ad)$ (which just permutes the disjuncts), so it is equivalent to an $L(Ad)$-formula $\chi(x,a',d)$ (this is a compactness argument). It follows that $\chi$ forks over $A$ and is in $\text{tp}(c/Ad)$, so we're done.